# How do many websites hide their file structure?

Tags: apache, apache-config

When I look at many large sites (e.g. wikipedia or this site) the urls looks like this:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StackOverflow
```

And not like:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki.php?article=StackOverflow
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki.pl?article=StackOverflow
... or even
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?article=StackOverflow
```

I suppose that wikipedia does not create a separate file for every article (and then use apache modules like mod_rewrite to hide the file extensions).

But how do they do this? Are they using a special server? Is there a way to configure apache to act like this? For example one script is called by every request and the path of the request is transmitted to the script, which will decide what to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called Friendly or Clean Urls .

Have a look at

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL
- http://www.petefreitag.com/item/503.cfm